# Advanced boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy, boolean-indexing

I wanna select values by mask and changes values by use mask-array.

Code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=(np.uint8, 3))
x = np.arange(4, dtype=int).reshape((2, 2))

mask = np.logical_and(a1 < 3, a1 > 0)

a[mask] = (1, x[mask], 2)
```

I want result:

```py
a[mask]
>> [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2]]
```

But i get error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

If try do things like `a[mask] = (1, 2, 2)`
array will be

```
[[[0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 2]],
[[1, 2, 2],
[0, 0, 0]]]
```

But i need use values from x.
To make it look like

```
[[[0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 3]],
[[1, 2, 3],
[0, 0, 0]]]
```

How i can do it?

Comment: `a = np.zeros((2, 2, 3), dtype=np.uint8)` is a clearer way to create that `a`.

Comment: What's `a1`?  A copy of `a`?  `x`? or something hidden?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two steps.

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=(np.uint8, 3)) 
x = np.arange(4, dtype=int).reshape((2, 2)) 
a1 = x  # Create an a1 for the mask

mask = np.logical_and(a1 < 3, a1 > 0) 

a[mask] = (1, 0, 2)      # Set the outer columns                                         
a[mask, 1] = x[mask]     # Set the column 1

print( a )                                                              
# [[[0 0 0]
#   [1 1 2]]

#  [[1 2 2]
#  [0 0 0]]]
```